# nameofrepo.git does not appear to be a git repository

Tags: git, capistrano, ssh-keys, gitolite

I´m trying to setup git on my own server and push my project there with capistrano.

it still says

> fatal: '/home/gitolite/repositories/iminrails.git' does not appear to
>   be a git repository
>   but i can see iminrails.git in directory repositories on server.
>   So i tried different process how to push my repo on server, but I´m still getting this error.

```
ofer@debianruby:/var/www/iminrails$ scp -r /tmp/iminrails.git gitolite@example.com:/home/gitolite/repositories/
Enter passphrase for key '/home/ofer/.ssh/id_rsa':
bad command: scp -r -t -- /home/gitolite/repositories/
lost connection
ofer@debianruby:/var/www/iminrails$ git push origin master:refs/heads/master
Enter passphrase for key '/home/ofer/.ssh/id_rsa':
fatal: '/home/gitolite/repositories/iminrails.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Comment: Your first command is failing even before you attempt to push. That should be fixed before the push error.

Comment: Try to access the server with `ssh` and to create the repository with `git init` to confirm that you have these permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Whe you are usng ssh with a gitolite account, you will use an ssh configure to use [forced command](http://oreilly.com/catalog/sshtdg/chapter/ch08.html#22858).
See [Gitolite and ssh](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/gl_ssh.html)

> If you look in the authorized_keys file, you'll see entries like this (I chopped off the ends of course; they're pretty long lines):

```
command="[path]/gl-auth-command sitaram",[more options] ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEA18S2t...
command="[path]/gl-auth-command usertwo",[more options] ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEArXtCT...
```

> First, it finds out which of the public keys in this file match the incoming login. That's crypto stuff, and I won't go into it.
>   Once the match has been found, it will run the command given on that line; e.g., if I logged in, it would run `[path]/gl-auth-command sitaram`.
>   So the first thing to note is that such users do not get "shell access", which is good!
>
> Before running the command, however, sshd sets up an environment variable called `SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND` which contains the actual git command that your workstation sent out. This is the command that would have run if you did not have the command= part in the authorised keys file.

The idea is simple:

- no interactive shell access
- git command only (so your scp command being *not* a git command), it is rejected.

If you need to copy an existing local Git repo to a remote Gitolite server, see "**[moving pre-existing repos into gitolite](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/moverepos.html)**"

> **let gitolite create it as a brand new repo** as described in the section on "[adding users and repos](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/add.html)".
>
> cd to the clone on your workstation.
>   Make sure all the branches are correct and no extra stuff, "temp" branches, etc., are present
>
> now run these two commands

```
git push --all git@server:reponame
git push --tags git@server:reponame
```